# VBA cambia a string una variable definida como Date

Tags: excel, vba

He definido las variables `finicio` y `ffin` como `Date` para guardar fechas introducidas con dos inputbox. `ffin` se mantiene como Date pero `finicio` se convierte a `String`. Las dos variables reciben exactamente el mismo trato.

Forzando la conversión a Date con `CDate(finicio)` sí funciona pero me gustaría saber por qué esta ocurriendo esto...

```
Sub CalculadoraAños()

    Sheets("Calculadora").Activate

    Dim fn, fMax, fMin, finicio, ffin As Date

    'Fecha actual
    fn = Date
    Range("D4") = fn

    'Fecha maxima
    fMax = DateAdd("m", -1, fn)
    Range("D6") = fMax

    'Fecha minima
    fMin = DateAdd("yyyy", -5, fn)
    Range("D5") = fMin

    'Fecha inicio
    finicio = InputBox("Pega la fecha de inicio: ")
    Range("D7") = finicio


    'Fecha fin
    ffin = InputBox("Pega la fecha de fin: ")
    Range("D8") = ffin

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En vba debes declarar cada variable independientemente, tú has hecho esto:

`Dim fn, fMax, fMin, finicio, ffin As Date`

o lo que es lo mismo:

`Dim fn As Variant, fMax As Variant, fMin As Variant, finicio As Variant, ffin As Date`

Sólo has declarado `ffin` como fecha, el resto son del tipo variant.

Esto es lo que debes hacer:

`Dim fn As Date, fmax As Date, fmin As Date, finicio As Date, ffin As Date`

Ya por último, a modo consejo, unos trucos para que tu código se vea más limpio son:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CalculadoraAños()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculadora")
        'Fecha actual
        Dim fn As Date
        fn = Date
        .Range("D4") = fn

        'Fecha maxima
        Dim fMax As Date
        fMax = DateAdd("m", -1, fn)
        .Range("D6") = fMax

        'Fecha minima
        Dim fMin As Date
        fMin = DateAdd("yyyy", -5, fn)
        .Range("D5") = fMin

        'Fecha inicio
        Dim finicio As Date
        finicio = InputBox("Pega la fecha de inicio: ")
        .Range("D7") = finicio


        'Fecha fin
        Dim ffin As Date
        ffin = InputBox("Pega la fecha de fin: ")
        .Range("D8") = ffin
    End With

End Sub
```

`Option Explicit` te obliga a declarar todas tus variables para evitar problemas.

Declarar cada variable justo antes de utilizarla te permite encontrar con mayor facilidad el tipo de variable que es y es más fácil de leer el código.

Utiliza los bloques `With` para hacer referencia a objetos como libros, hojas o rangos. Así no necesitas utilizar `.Select` o `.Activate` y evitas posibles errores. Es tan fácil como hacer referencia al objeto que quieres con el with, y luego utilizar un `.` delante de lo que sea, en este ejemplo, delante de `Range`.

Comment: Damian habla con verdad y esta es la mejor respuesta :)

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!